# TurnItIn on Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

We're trying to turn TurnItIn on for distinct course sites in our Desire2Learn environment. 
As far as we can determine, to do this now we have to do this for each ou in the DOME manually.

Is there anything in the API that we can leverage to create a 'form' to enable this across all org units?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 10 of Desire2Learn suite there are no apis to control dome config.